# Rails 3, find current view while in the layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, layout

I have a scenario where I would like to have the name of the view that will be rendering while I'm in the layout file. I can find solutions to find which layout will be wrapping the current view from the view, but not the other way around. How can I find which view is rendering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Rails 3.0.3, I was able to see the name of the controller and action using controller_name and action_name. But those are not publicly documented (at least the action name) so I wouldn't depend on it long-term.

It might be better to monkey patch template render. In an initializer:

```
module ActionView::Rendering 
  alias_method :_render_template_original, :_render_template
  def _render_template(template, layout = nil, options = {}) 
    @last_template = template
    _render_template_original(template, layout, options)
  end
end
```

Then use @last_template in your layout.

Comment: This worked great for me. To add a bit more detail, in Rails 3 I added this to a new file config/initializers/custom_renderer.rb, and then in the view I was able to access @last_template.variable_name to get, for example, "new"

Comment: `ActionView::Rendering` does not exist in Rails 3.1 anymore.

Answer (score 5):

The following solution works in Rails 3.1. Place this code in an initializer.
(The rails 3.0.3 answer is not working any more in Rails 3.1)

This enables an @active_template variable for every controller. This is an instance of an ActionViewTemplate class.

The method active_template_virtual_path method returns the template as a name in the following form "controller/action"

```
    class ActionController::Base
      attr_accessor :active_template

      def active_template_virtual_path
        self.active_template.virtual_path if self.active_template
      end
    end

    class ActionView::TemplateRenderer 

      alias_method :_render_template_original, :render_template

      def render_template(template, layout_name = nil, locals = {})

        @view.controller.active_template = template if @view.controller
        result = _render_template_original( template, layout_name, locals)
        @view.controller.active_template = nil if @view.controller
        return result

      end
    end
```

Comment: This works for me with Rails 3.1.3. Although I shortened the solution a bit: `@view.assign(:active_template => template)` inside of `render_template`, then you can remove a bunch of the extra code and access the template inside a view as `@active_template`.

Comment: I found that this gave the 'exception_notification' gem some trouble. To fix this I made [these changes](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sd8f01mp).

Comment: I had a problem with nested layouts (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts). The active_template was set to my top-most layout rather than the view from the controller.

To fix, I added an extra condition on the assginment:
`@view.controller.active_template = template if @view.controller && @view.controller.active_template.nil?`

Answer (score 0):

I like the following approach, as you can reduce code size a good bit in a lot of cases.  Include this in your application_controller.rb:

```
  before_filter :instantiate_controller_and_action_names
  caches_action :instantiate_controller_and_action_names

  def instantiate_controller_and_action_names
    @current_action = action_name
    @current_controller = controller_name
  end
```

Then, if your views correspond to an action, you just do:

```
dosomething if @current_action == 'new'
```

Comment: This doesn't quite solve the issue I have. I need the name of the view, and it not always the same as the action being called.

Comment: Just add a blank action then, for instance def whatever end.