# Easy way to find a view file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I develop rails applications with my designer who has minimum knowledge about rails.
She works on Windows through file-sharing from a Linux server.
She always has hard time finding view files to work on.

I usually use 'grep' to find a view file.
But she can't.

If you have a good suggestion, please share with me.

I have an idea which may be overkill.
Is there a way to automatically add comments around view files (including layouts and partials?) in html file?

Like this:

```
<!--Starting app/views/some_dir/some_file.html.erb-->
HTML here...
<!--Ending app/views/some_dir/some_file.html.erb-->
```

This way, my designer can find the file very easily.
Of course, this should be automatic and development environment only.

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: what do you think about gnuwin or something else to give her the 'grep' command ? Or may be this other post can be usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973699/rails-3-find-current-view-while-in-the-layout

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Does the file directory differ on her machine than on yours? Such that you are not able to ask her to look in "app/views/etc"?

Comment: @MrDanA: No, the file directory is the same. Usually I tell her to modify a specific web page (URL) instead of a specific view file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the Rails Footnotes gem (https://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes) in some of my projects which allows me to click a link in the footer of my app that opens the current view (also shows partials) in TextMate. Not sure if it could be customised to work with a Windows text editor but you could look at the URL to work out the file name.

I.e to open a file in MacVim, it creates the following link:

`mvim://open?url=file:///Users/steveholt/Sites/foo/app/views/projects/log.html.haml`

and for TextMate:

`txmt://open?url=file:///Users/steveholt/Sites/foo/app/views/projects/log.html.haml`

Comment: This seems very close to what I want. Thanks.

Comment: amazing stuff, it's close to developer tool for magento