# How to change flash[:notice] placement only on one page in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notice

I need to place all my flash notices below header, except of one page.

Only on one page I should place it differently.

**EDIT**

I added in my acton, where I want to use another layout this line:

```
  render :layout => 'show'
```

and now, when I'm going to show page it gives me:

```
  undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass
```

but without rendering THIS layout - no errors.

**EDIT**

Is it possible in Rails ?

Comment: Use layouts. For example, one layout is main, there you render your flash, and the second is your different layout with specific flash rendering

Comment: @Denis, привет тёзка) When I created `show` layout strange errors begun to raise.

Comment: What kind of errors? Posting them will help.

Comment: I'm using the same DEFAULT layout, but WITHOUT notice messages.

Comment: You don't have to copy whole layout just for 1 change. Why don't you show flash with an if condition? if current_page etc...

Comment: If this page I need to move it in other place. How can I make it ?

Comment: If you're planning to put the flash message on a specific template, you can add a condition that disables the flash message on the specific template.

Comment: @beef, I can't run specific template because of strange error, that I posted.

Comment: wait, I thought those errors were because of the new layout you used (layouts/show.html.erb)? Try to just add a condition where that flash message is showing, and add the flash message on the specific template (ex: controller_name/template.html.erb).

Comment: @beef, yeah you understood me right. when I'm using code, that I posted it gives me error. WHat you can tell about that ?

Comment: You're probably calling url on an object which can't be accessed by your views. But as Emrah suggested, you can just use an if condition instead of creating a new layout just for that, seems like a waste.

Comment: You can set an instance var, say @ template_name and something like = render flash[:notice] if @ template_name == "something", though it seems pretty hackish. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973699/rails-3-find-current-view-while-in-the-layout. Although I'm now thinking creating a new layout seems the better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you could just do a check on the current controller#action in the view to see if our flash messages need to be moved.

Rails passes these params to every view (ex: if we were in the `show` action of `UsersController`):

```
params[:controller] #=> users
params[:action]     #=> show
```

We could add a helper to simplify our condition in the view:

```
# file: app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def move_flash_messages?
  params[:controller] == "users" && params[:action] == "show"
end
```

And then do this simple check in our layout:

```
# file: app/views/layouts/application.html.haml
- unless move_flash_messages?
  = flash_messages
...
- if move_flash_messages?
  = flash_messages
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to show flash message anywhere

```
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: "flash notice" , id:"flash_notice" %>
  <% end %>
```

here is css for flash message

```
div.flash.notice {
  background: url(../images/true.png) 8px 5px no-repeat;
  background-color: #dfffdf;
  border-color: #9fcf9f;
  color: #005f00;
}
```